# "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA" error when using function mean [R]

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I used the [Ames data set](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v19n3/decock/AmesHousing.xls) to create the following code:

```
NbrMLR <- lm(SalePrice ~ Neighborhood, data = ames_housing_data)
pred <- as.data.frame(predict(NbrMLR, ames_housing_data))
library(reshape)
pred <- rename(pred,c('predict(NbrMLR, ames_housing_data)' = 'prd'))
ames_housing_data$NbrPred <- pred
ames_housing_data$NbrRes <- SalePrice - ames_housing_data$NbrPred
ames_housing_data$absoluteNbrRes <- abs(ames_housing_data$NbrRes)
NbrMAE <- mean(ames_housing_data$absoluteNbrRes)
```

This code results in the following error:

> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

`str(ames_housing_data$absoluteNbrRes)` tells that I have a data frame of variable type `$ prd: num`. Though I'm familiar with `num`, I've never heard of `prd: num` before. Does this cause problem? Why does not `mean()` act upon what otherwise seems to me to be a valid vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ames_housing_data$NbrPred <- pred[[1]]` will fix it.

Regarding your error: `prd` is a variable name (as you defined it!). You pass a data frame to `mean`, which causes you error.

---

If I were you, I would write the following code:

```
NbrMLR <- lm(SalePrice ~ Neighborhood, data = ames_housing_data)
ames_housing_data$NbrPred <- predict(NbrMLR, ames_housing_data)
ames_housing_data$NbrRes <- SalePrice - ames_housing_data$NbrPred
ames_housing_data$absoluteNbrRes <- abs(ames_housing_data$NbrRes)
NbrMAE <- mean(ames_housing_data$absoluteNbrRes)
```